# Failed to start project The directory name is invalid

Tags: sql-server, excel, visual-studio, ssis, etl

I'm new and learning SSIS, and just to get started I wanted to test funtionality by writing an excel document out to a .csv file. However, I did everything that I believe needs to be done, but when I try to run it, I get this error:

> Failed to start project (Microsoft Visual Studio)
>   The directory name is invalid (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

I've run over it about as many ways as I can, and even went as far as reinstalling, but I still can't get it to work. Looking up this error doesn't return much to me, either.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you follow steps for your version/bit as per this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/aa3a46fb-2f09-4808-b6db-baa1553f6401/failed-to-start-project-microsoft-visual-studio?forum=sqlintegrationservices    p.s. Is this you under a different guise?

Comment: Not me, but I did see it and tried what was recommended, but it made no difference

Comment: @Bryn welcome to stackoverflow, feel free to read the [Tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com.Tour) to read more about asking question, accepting answers and other features, and to get your "Informed" badge

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem. I had Visual Studio 2017 installed and standalone SSDT tools installed as well.

The latest version of SQL server installed on my machine was SQL server 2014.

Thus, I changed the project properties of the integration services project.

> General -> Deployment target version -> TargetServerVersion
>
> from SQL Server 2017 to SQL Server 2014

and it worked finally for me.

Answer (score 0):

First result on Google says this is [a DLL error](https://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/missing-not-found-error/dll/windows/microsoft/msdn-disc-2729/microsoft-datatransformationservices-vsintegration-dll/).

[From this answer:](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7aff86e-564e-4a35-adb7-e48aebb7a09c/fail-to-start-project?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

1. Open the Developer Command Prompt for VS212 as Administrator
2. Execute the command cd `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies`
3. Execute the command `gacutil /if Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Design.dll`
4. Restart Visual Studio

Comment: Tried this, same error. All I've done is make a data flow task, then inside of  it make an Excel Source, clicked "New" for connection manager, browsed to the .xlsx file I want, confirmed that it read it correctly by looking at the "columns", hit "OK", then right-clicked and hit "Execute Task". I get this error: The directory name is invalid (Microsoft Visual Studio)

Comment: Program Location:

   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.LaunchVsDebugger(IVsDebugger iVsDebugger, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32 flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DtsPackagesFolderProjectFeature.ExecuteTaskOrPackage(ProjectItem prjItem, String taskPath)

Comment: What happens if you run SSIS as administrator?

Comment: same result. I even tried to just read a csv file, but got the same issue again

Comment: Can you use SSMS to import a file and record the SSIS package it generates and check the connection details in that?

Comment: Good point. @Bryn try creating a new package. If you changed any settings after you created the package, the error may be in your current package.

Comment: I used SSMS to go from an excel file to a csv, ran it successfully and saved the package. I opened the package in VS, but I can't run it from there. I then opened a second VS window, and recreated the package exactly the same as the saved package, but when I try to run it I get the same error...

Comment: Try a different directory name, different columns, and different output name.

Answer (score 0):

There are some SSDT assemblies missing, I think that you have to reinstall or to repair the Sql Server Data Tools, you can find the latest versions on the following link:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

Answer (score 0):

I know it's being a long time since question was posted but I just had the same error and the fix was as follow:

In the SSIS Project properties I had to change two configurations:

1. Target SQL server ( from 2017 to 2016 )
2. Run in 64-bit mode ( from true to false )

After that everything start working.